# How to use several similar CircuitLab schematics in one post without redrawing the whole diagram?

Tags: support

Sometimes I want to use two or more circuit diagrams in one post, which are only slight variations of each other.

Is it possible to "continue" an existing schematic and then insert it as a new separate schematic ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way:

Create the initial schematic the usual way. Do you stuff on CircuitLab, and when the first version is done, click "Save and Insert". That makes you go back to EE.SE, and there is now some markup in your answer text that looks like this:

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/*****.png)

<!-- End schematic -->
```

Copy this entire part as many times you want in your post. This will make as many instances of your schematic in your post. For each instance, you'll have a "edit the above schematic" link. If you click it, you can modify the instances you want individually. When you "Save and Insert" from CircuitLab for a given instance, the corresponding link (the `*****.png`) part will change for the modified instance, but it will not update the other instances, and the original schematic will be preserved.

You can even use the same technique to reuse, possibly with some modifications, a schematic from another post. Go to the source post that contains the schematic, click "Edit" as if you wanted to modify the post: that will show you the markup text. From there, copy the schematic block as shown above, cancel the post edit, and paste the block in your destination post. You can use the schematic as is, or modify it (the original schematic, of course, won't change).

Comment: Thanks. That last paragraph is especially useful when replying to a question, whose schematic you want to annotate/modify.

Comment: A word of warning. I have found that editing a post with multiple CircuitLab schematics can be risky. One more than one occasion, I have lost significant work I have done on the schematics. I believe the interface to be buggy, so I suggest backing up your changes by completing an edit when you are done with each schematic, rather than waiting till you are done with all.